# Independent producers in Kafka using Spring Boot and load balancer

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I have installed Apache Kafka from Confluent (with rest-api and schema-registry). I implemented producer using spring-boot and spring-kafka (each event has uuid generated in database trigger). Now I would like to run it as multiple instances - but what is the proper way of omitting duplicates in kafka? If I have few instances of spring-boot behind of load balancer and each of it has event with the same generated uuid, how to send just one to kafka? I can generate uuid in spring but content of event still will be the same and there is no point to send it from every instance (database's trigger will send content to each producer anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look into the Apache Kafka [Log Compaction](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture-log-compaction/index.html) feature:

> Log compaction retains at least the last known value for each record key for a single topic partition. Compacted logs are useful for restoring state after a crash or system failure.

So, your UUIDs become as record keys and only one record of this key will be available for the consumer on the other side.

Comment: In your opinion it is not an overkill? I will almost have 0ms for compaction.lag.ms - so cleaning after every written single event :) Compacting is not blocking I/O, but still it requires some resources from server

Comment: There is no other way to restrict data from the producer side, more over they are independent instances. Well, you can store data into DB using primary key for your UUID and on the other side poll already this table before sending to the Kafka. Another solution might be like `filter` on the consumer side - if you get the record with the same `key`, just ignore it. Here is some solution from Spring Kafka: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_filtering_messages